# Footer that doesn't conflict with borders of website?

Tags: html, css

So I've been trying to make a footer for this website I've been working on for a class but I can't seem to find a working solution. My issue is that the footer will usually overlap the borders of my site, and if they don't the text that I want to put in the footer then goes UNDER the border. I've tried quite a few footers but none seem to fit what I want.

```
html {
background-color:silver;
border:9px black solid;
margin:0px; padding:0px; width:auto; height:auto;
}
```

This is the CSS which creates the border, if any more info needs to be provided just ask me!

Comment: You can make width of the footer smaller or set higher z-index for the borders.

Comment: Please post a simplified version of your html and css so we can have a look what is wront with the code. By the way... do you think this code can solve your problem: https://jsfiddle.net/ohbsq5na/ ???

Comment: Welp, I feel dumb now. Just another question though, what exactly is the z-index for? Just increasing where something is on the page on the z axis right?

Comment: z-index is something like sent to back, bring to front, if you remember that from your school working with miscrosoft products. If you want something to be always on top, set it the highest z-index: 1000; (example). If you want something always to be in the back then z-index: -1; (or just lower than 1000)

Comment: Could you add your html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the border for your whole page, you shouldn't set it on the html. It should look more like this.

```
<html>
     <body>
          <div class="wrapper">
          <footer class="footer"> </footer>
          </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

And css:

```
.wrapper {
border:1px solid black:
z-index: 1000;
}

.footer {
z-index: 1;
}
```